# Does @Retryable open new threads in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

When we use @Retryable or retryTemplate with backoff policy in spring are the retryable method executed in a new thread when an exception is thrown and the main thread is blocked for the time being or all the retry attempts are executed in a single thread .

Comment: I don't think that it is creating new thread. It is blocking newly spawned thread for this Retry and keep it with it. Tested it.